# Is it necessary keys to have equal propabillities for the system to have perfect secrecy?

Tags: perfect-secrecy

Shannon's theorem for perfect secrecy states that
$$\forall x \in M, y \in C:\quad P[x|y]=P[x] $$
I know we need $|M|\leq |C| \leq |K|$.
If $|Μ|=|C|=|K|$ all keys should have equal probs.
If $|Μ|<|Κ|$ **is it still necessary?**
I think not because :
$$P[x|c_i]=P[x|c_j] \implies \sum_{k_i: E_{k_i}(m_i)=c_i}P[K=k_i]=\sum_{k_i:E_{k_i}(m_i)=c_i}P[k=k_j]$$
The difference is that when $|Μ|=|C|=|K|$ there is exactly one $k $ s.t: $Ε_k(m)=c$ while now there may be more .

Is my conclusion valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my conclusion valid?

Yes, it is.

I'll give you a simple example of such a system: we have a 1 bit plaintext, 2 bits of key and 1 bit of ciphertext; the encryption method is:

$$C = K_0 \oplus K_1 \oplus P$$

(where $K_0, K_1$ are the two bits of the key); with the probabilities of the key bits are:

- 00 with probability 0.1
- 01 with probability 0.2
- 10 with probability 0.3
- 11 with probability 0.4

Simple calculation shows that this scheme achieves perfect secrecy, even though the key is nonuniformly distributed.